# How to call function from array JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im practicing JS and trying to execute a sample code by calling function from array but it returns undefined with output from the function. I am unable to understand how it works as I have called the index of the array having function but its showing two outputs when i expect 1.

```
const arr = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    function(){console.log("hi")}
];

console.log(arr[2]());
```

**Output:**

```
Babel Compiler v6.4.4
Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Sebastian McKenzie
   
hi
undefined
=> undefined
```

Comment: You have two `console.log`, so why do you expect one output?

Answer (score 0):

The function itself already logs "hi" and doesnt return anything.
console. log(arr2 ) prints the return value though (which doesnt exist and therefore always is undefined)

A function that would do what you are (probably) trying to do would look like this:

```
function() {return "hi" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you have just to call `arr[2]()` like this:

```js
const arr = [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        function(){console.log("hi")}
    ];

arr[2]();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `console.log` when you invoking the function means you are printing the return value of the function.

Just try the following by adding the return value that should explain.

```js
const arr = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    function(){console.log("hi")},
    function(){console.log("hello"); return "world"}
];

console.log('1. function return value here: ', arr[2]());
console.log('2. function return value here: ', arr[3]());
```